# Whenever I use an google maps API key it doesn’t work

Tags: google-maps

I can’t seem to use they API key I generated when running the android emulators. The very first app I made with any API key I generated works but anytime I make a new app and plug in the API key it doesn’t work. It says it’s having trouble with google play services. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to use the same API key with all the different apps? Have you added all of the app IDs to the key configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the API key is restricted to your first app where you used the API key, I would suggest that you use new API key for each app that you make as this will also help you track your usage for each app that you make.

You may also see the [API key best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices) to help you in restricting your API key to avoid unexpected usage.